# AngularJS read response data from http post to Tastypie API

Tags: javascript, django, api, angularjs, tastypie

I have a issue where i am trying to create a post request which actually also returns the response data.

I have configured my api so that when a post is successful it gives the object back as a response. I want to do this so i can retrieve the correct id that has been assigned to it.

My Order method, which is the one i am using looks like this.

```
posServices.factory('Order', ['$resource', '$http',
  function($resource, $http){
    return $resource(APIURL + 'order/?username=' + APIUSER + '&api_key=' + APIKEY + '' + '&limit=0', {}, {
        create: {
            method:'POST',
            params:{},
            transformResponse: tastypieDataTransformer($http),
            isArray: true
        }
    });
  }
]);
```

I would like to be able to to do something like this in my controller:

```
var response = Order.create('{"paymentMethod":"' + $scope.paymentMethod + '"}');
```

I am fairly new to angularJS, just to throw that out there.

**EDIT:**
I have figured out that the data is actually here, but i cant seem to find a way to get it into my variable in the controller. If i console.log() from my transform function i get the correct information out, but i cant figure out why i cant get it where i want it.

**EDIT 2:**
Seems like i was pretty noob:
isArray: true
Removing this fixed the problem.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: The response variable just come out as a empty []. I cant figure out how i get the data out.

Comment: Why not use a conditional statement that checks for a POST, and if the POST is made, it then activates a GET request. This may work instead of using a POST request only.

Comment: @Joe  : The reason why i wanted to do this in this way was to be 100% certain that i got the right id for the newly created order. Since i dont know the ID how do i know what to GET... If there is a smart way i would love to hear it:) I dont think that to get, and select the latest seems like a good idea.

Comment: You could tie the 2 together so that one follows directly after the other. For example, you could nest one in the other.